# How to compare values between two dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have below mentioned two dataframe:

where i want to compare each column of DF_2 with DF_1 corresponding to Unique `ID` and in `Dif` column i want to get the exact time difference in Minute between DF_2 and DF_1, and in ST,ST2 and ST3 columns in Required Output i want to match the respective column of DF_2 with DF_1.

DF_1

```
ID     Date                  Val1     Val2   Val3
AB-55  2017-01-04 18:25:14   adj.f@f  ad2er  25
AB-78  2017-01-08 08:48:14   arj.t@y  ar8ey  258
AB-48  2017-01-09 21:25:45   edR.u@t  wu5eu  75
```

DF_2

```
ID     Date                  Val1     Val2   Val3
AB-55  2017-01-04 18:25:14   adj.f@f  ad2er  25
AB-78  2017-01-08 08:58:14   arj.t@y  ar7ey  25
AB-48  2017-01-09 21:25:45   edR.u@t  wu5eu  75
```

Required Dataframe:

```
ID     Date                Dif   Val1    ST   Val2  ST2   Val3 ST3
AB-55  2017-01-04 18:25:14 0     adj.f@f T    ad2er T     25   T
AB-78  2017-01-08 08:48:14 10    arj.t@y T    ar8ey F     258  F
AB-48  2017-01-09 21:25:45 0     edR.u@t T    wu5eu T     75   T
```

Comment: If the dataframes have the same rows in the same order then difftime(DF_1$Date, DF_2$Date, units = "mins") should provide with a vector of differences

Comment: @griffinevo the sequence of the raw are not same...that can be identified by `ID` only.

Comment: `inner_join(DF_1, DF_2, by = 'ID') %>% mutate(...)`

Comment: @Roy1245 just saw your comment, try out my answer below - if it works then accept, if not comment and I'll try to find the solution - all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `difftime` which **will work assuming you have the same rows in each data frame**.

```
DF_1$Dif <- as.numeric(difftime(DF_2$Date, DF_1$Date, units = "mins"))
```

...and the data frame:

```
> DF_1
     ID                Date Dif
1 AB-55 2017-01-04 18:25:14   0
2 AB-78 2017-01-08 08:48:14  10
```

Alternatively, **if the rows don't match up**, first implement a `merge` first:

```
DF_3 <- merge(DF_1, DF_2, by = "ID", all.x = T, all.y = T)
DF_3$Dif <- as.numeric(difftime(DF_3$Date.y, DF_3$Date.x, units = "mins"))
```

And the result...

```
> DF_3
     ID              Date.x              Date.y Dif
1 AB-55 2017-01-04 18:25:14 2017-01-04 18:25:14   0
2 AB-78 2017-01-08 08:48:14 2017-01-08 08:58:14  10
3 AB-89 2017-01-08 10:35:14                <NA>  NA
4 AD-87                <NA> 2017-01-08 06:15:12  NA
```

To **include the other columns**, as requested in the edits you made to the question:

```
# Here I'm just making your dataframe, please provide code to make reproducible data where possible in the future
DF_1 <- data.frame("ID" = c("AB-55", "AB-78", "AB-89"), "Date" = c("2017-01-04 18:25:14", "2017-01-08 08:48:14", "2017-01-08 10:35:14")) 
DF_2 <- data.frame("ID" = c("AB-55", "AB-78", "AD-87"), "Date" = c("2017-01-04 18:25:14", "2017-01-08 08:58:14", "2017-01-08 06:15:12")) 

DF_1$Val1 <- c("adj.f@f", "adj.t@y", "edR.u@t")
DF_2$Val1 <- c("adj.f@f", "adj.t@y", "edR.u@t")

DF_1$Val2 <- c("ad2er", "ar7ey", "wu5eu")
DF_2$Val2 <- c("ad2er", "ar8ey", "wu5eu")

DF_1$Val3 <- c(25, 258, 75)
DF_2$Val3 <- c(25,  25, 75)

# The merge and difftime part remains
DF_3 <- merge(DF_1, DF_2, by = "ID", all.x = T, all.y = T)
DF_3$Dif <- as.numeric(difftime(DF_3$Date.y, DF_3$Date.x, units = "mins"))

# True/False part
DF_3$ST1 <- DF_3$Val1.x == DF_3$Val1.y
DF_3$ST2 <- DF_3$Val2.x == DF_3$Val2.y
DF_3$ST3 <- DF_3$Val3.x == DF_3$Val3.y
```

And the **data frame**:

```
DF_3


> DF_3
     ID              Date.x  Val1.x Val2.x Val3.x              Date.y  Val1.y Val2.y Val3.y Dif  ST1   ST2   ST3
1 AB-55 2017-01-04 18:25:14 adj.f@f  ad2er     25 2017-01-04 18:25:14 adj.f@f  ad2er     25   0 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
2 AB-78 2017-01-08 08:48:14 adj.t@y  ar7ey    258 2017-01-08 08:58:14 adj.t@y  ar8ey     25  10 TRUE FALSE FALSE
3 AB-89 2017-01-08 10:35:14 edR.u@t  wu5eu     75                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>     NA  NA   NA    NA    NA
4 AD-87                <NA>    <NA>   <NA>     NA 2017-01-08 06:15:12 edR.u@t  wu5eu     75  NA   NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: @grifflinevo Thanks but i want to check the others columns of DF_2 with DF_1 and want to know the status T (True) or F (False).

Comment: see edits - adding those columns it works as required (don't underestimate the value of providing code to make reproducible data)